# List implementation using size_t doesn't match the wanted constructor

Tags: c++, list

I try to make a simple C++ `std::list` implementation and I have encountered a problem with my constructors. I have a set of constructors:

```
List();
List(size_t Size);
List(size_t Size, const T& Val);
List(const std::initializer_list<T>& Init);
template<typename It> List(It It1, It It2);
```

And a piece of code that creates an instance of the List class:

```
int main()
{
    List<int> l(10, 9);
}
```

Obviously, I want to make use of this constructor:

```
List(size_t Size, const T& Val);
```

But instead it uses this constructor:

```
template<typename It> List(It It1, It It2);
```

I know that `size_t` is the source of the problem. If I changed `size_t` to `int`, everything would work properly.
So is there any possibility to use `List(size_t Size, const T& Val);` using `size_t`, not the `template<typename It> List(It It1, It It2);`?

Comment: `It` should be limited to iterating class (SFINAE or concepts are required)